# Constructing queries with graql Java API

Tags: java, vaticle-typeql

What's the difference between `QueryBuilder` and `QueryParser`. Which one should I use for constructing queries?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `QueryBuilder` for beginning to build a query.

`QueryParser` allows you to parse Graql query strings into Java Graql objects.

---

Take a look to [**this link**](https://mindmaps.io/pages/documentation/graql/java-graql.html) for more information.